# How to prevent Android from booting into Safe Mode?

Tags: device-administrator, safe-mode

I'm hoping to remove access to Safe Mode on my own device. I want to explore the possibility of making it more difficult to circumvent self-restriction apps such as the popular AppBlock app (and things similar to Focus mode found in Digital Wellbeing by Google).

Is it possible to prevent access to Safe Mode?

I do not have a rooted device but I am open to rooting it, if necessary.

Comment: If you know Android app development you can create a Device Policy Manager and setup this policy in it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager#DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT

Comment: I don't know Android development, but policies and what you referred to sound like the mechanism to make this work. I think that means I should look into remote admin tools that utilize policies. This would provide the effect of disabling safe mode. As I'm writing this, I'm not sure why I didn't consider that earlier. Thank you.